# Check if a link has been clicked in the past day

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, click, show-hide

I am trying to make a simple personal homepage for myself by using local html and Jquery. I added a link that goes to Bing Rewards.

```
<a id="bing" href="https://www.bing.com/rewards/dashboard">Bing Rewards</a>
```

However, I only want to go to this website once per day. When I click on it, I want it to hide until the next day.

```
$('#bing').click(function(){
   $(this).hide();
}
```

When I close and re-open the page, how would I make it so that it knows the last time I accessed the link, and based on that, either shows the link or not?
I'm pretty new at this kind of stuff, so the simpler the answer, the better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following will hide or show button on page load and store time in localStorage.

If page is to stay open for long periods you would want to run an interval timer to check date difference

```
var lastBing = localStorage.getItem('last_bing'),
    now = new Date(),
    showButton = true;       
if (lastBing) {
    lastBing = new Date(+lastBing);
    showButton = lastBing.setDate(lastBing.getDate() + 1) < now;
}

$('#bing').click(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('last_bing', +new Date());
    $(this).hide();
}).toggle(showButton);
```

Comment: Thanks for the short and simple answer!

Answer (score 1):

In this method, the day (from midnight) of the last click is stored in local storage ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/0q57mxkd/1/))

```
$(function() {
  var oneDay = 8.64e7, // 24 hours in milliseconds
    lastClicked = localStorage.getItem('bing-time'),
    showLink = new Date().getTime() > lastClicked + oneDay;
  $('#bing').toggle(showLink);
  if (showLink) {
    $('#bing').on('click', function() {
      var date = new Date();
      // set time to midnight
      date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
      localStorage.setItem('bing-time', date);
      $(this).hide();
    });
  }

  // reset localstorage - for demo
  $('button').click(function() {
    localStorage.removeItem('bing-time');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the click time in cookie. Using some library like [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) will be much easy.

```
$('#bing').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();

    // set cookies to expire in 14 days
    Cookies.set('bing-click-time', new Date(), {
        expires : 14
    });
});
var clickTime = Cookies.get('bing-click-time');
if (clickTime != undefined) {
    var cTime = new Date(clickTime);
    var diff = new Date().getTime() - cTime.getTime();
    console.log(clickTime, cTime, cTime.getTime(), diff / (1000 * 60))
    if (diff / (1000 * 60) < 3) {// eg: less than 3 min
        $('#bing').hide();
    }
}
```